# Rectangles will not draw when I call the .invalidate method?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to draw rectangles on the screen which I will later add code to make them move across the screen as the objective of the game I am making is to tilt a ball through gaps in the rectangles to keep them from pushing the ball off the screen. Here is some code from the game activity:

```
public class GameScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

BallView mBallView = null;
Rectangle rect1 = null
        , rect2= null
        , rect3 = null
        , rect4= null
        , rect5 = null
        , rect6= null;
Handler RedrawHandler = new Handler(); //so redraw occurs in main thread
Timer mTmr = null;
TimerTask mTsk = null;
int mScrWidth, mScrHeight;
android.graphics.PointF mBallPos, mBallSpd;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //hide title bar
    //set app to full screen and keep screen on
    getWindow().setFlags(0xFFFFFFFF, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);
    //create pointer to main screen
    final FrameLayout mainView = (android.widget.FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

    //get screen dimensions
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mScrWidth = display.getWidth();
    mScrHeight = display.getHeight();
    mBallPos = new android.graphics.PointF();
    mBallSpd = new android.graphics.PointF();




    //create variables for ball position and speed
    mBallPos.x = mScrWidth / 5;
    mBallPos.y = mScrHeight / 2;
    mBallSpd.x = 0;
    mBallSpd.y = 0;

    //create initial ball
    mBallView = new BallView(this, mBallPos.x, mBallPos.y, 75);

    //**************Create initial rectangle****************
    rect1 = new Rectangle(this, 1000, 500, 1000, 500);
    rect1.invalidate();



    mainView.addView(mBallView); //add ball to main screen
    mBallView.invalidate(); //call onDraw in BallView

    //listener for accelerometer, use anonymous class for simplicity
    ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).registerListener(
            new SensorEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                    //set ball speed based on phone tilt (ignore Z axis)
                    mBallSpd.x = -event.values[0] * (30/10);
                    mBallSpd.y = event.values[1] * (30/10);
                    //timer event will redraw ball
                }

                @Override
                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                } //ignore
            },
            ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
                    .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


} //OnCreate

//listener for menu button on phone
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Exit"); //only one menu item
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//listener for menu item clicked
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    if (item.getTitle() == "Exit") //user clicked Exit
        finish(); //will call onPause
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//For state flow see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
@Override
public void onPause() //app moved to background, stop background threads
{
    mTmr.cancel(); //kill\release timer (our only background thread)
    mTmr = null;
    mTsk = null;
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onResume() //app moved to foreground (also occurs at app startup)
{
    //create timer to move ball to new position
    mTmr = new Timer();
    mTsk = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            //if debugging with external device,
//  a log cat viewer will be needed on the device
            Log.d("TiltBall", "Timer Hit - " + mBallPos.x + ":" + mBallPos.y);

//move ball based on current speed
            mBallPos.x += mBallSpd.y;
            mBallPos.y += -mBallSpd.x;

            //if ball goes off screen, reposition to opposite side of screen
            if (mBallPos.x > mScrWidth) mBallPos.x = 0;
            if (mBallPos.y > mScrHeight) mBallPos.y = 0;
            if (mBallPos.x < 0) mBallPos.x = mScrWidth;
            if (mBallPos.y < 0) mBallPos.y = mScrHeight;

            //update ball class instance
            mBallView.x = mBallPos.x;
            mBallView.y = mBallPos.y;
//redraw ball. Must run in background thread to prevent thread lock.
            RedrawHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mBallView.invalidate();
                }
            });




            //If ball hits sides it goes to the redirect screen, YOU LOSE!
            if (mBallPos.y  == mScrHeight || mBallPos.y == 0 || mBallPos.x == mScrWidth|| mBallPos.x == 0 ) {

                goToRedirectScreen();
            }




        } //run
    }; // TimerTask

    mTmr.schedule(mTsk, 10, 10); //start timer
    super.onResume();
} // onResume
```

And here is the Rectangle class I made:

```
public class Rectangle extends View {

public float left;
public float top;
public float right;
public float bottom;
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


//construct new rectangle object
public Rectangle(Context context, float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    super(context);

    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF);  //not transparent. color is white
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.right = right;
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

//qcalled by invalidate()
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);
} }
```

Whenever I call the .invalidate method to use .onDraw of my Rectangle class nothing comes up on the screen and I can't see where I went wrong. I have also tried using .postInvalidate and that doesnt work either.

Comment: Where is `rect1` supposed to be drawn? You've not added it to any onscreen View; e.g., `mainView`.

Comment: @MikeM. I added rect1 to the main view using .addView and I called invalidate and still nothing happened......

Comment: `Rectangle(this, 1000, 500, 1000, 500)` - Your rectangle has no width or height. That is, its `left` and `right` values are both 1000, and the `top` and `bottom` are both 500.

Comment: @MikeM. Oooooooo, wow haha I am really dumb, it works now...THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH MIKE!!! You have literally made my day :)

Comment: After re-examining your code, I don't think it's going to work as you're expecting. It seems like the `BallView` class handles its dimensions itself (I'm guessing, because of the last argument in its constructor). The way you're implementing the `Rectangle` class, I suspect you're only going to see one `Rectangle` on-screen.

Comment: @MikeM. Well yes I still have to add the other 5 rectangles code wise, currently only 1 is showing and I still have to adjust it's position......but it would work then right? Is there a certain method I can use to get the 6 rectangles I am going to draw to shift left at X speed? If you don't know, no problem you have already helped me ALOT

Comment: No, I mean, with your code as it is, I think you're only ever going to see one Rectangle, no matter how many you add. You're not specifying any LayoutParams when adding them to the FrameLayout, so they will each fill their parent by default, the last one added showing on top. Also, the Rectangle class does not adjust its own dimensions in any way, so they will all fill the parent, one stacked on top of another. You can test this simply by adding another Rectangular or two, and seeing what you get.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok I just added 3 rectangles and all are separate from each other, that is none overlap......so I don't understand what you mean...since it worked is my code fine now?

Comment: Right, I had forgotten that the default background for Views is transparent. As to whether it works, that's up to you and how you need your app to behave.